# "perfume" vs. "perfumes"

Tags: word-choice

I don't know what to choose in such a situation:

> - Your perfume/perfumes smells/smell nice. What is it? / What are they?
> - It's a new perfume called Sunshine.  / They're new perfumes called Sunshine.

Is there any principle of using these words? Are both versions in use?
Please, let me know which version would be the best.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perfume and perfumes have different uses. Perfume is not a countable noun in English; you cannot normally give it a number because it is not divided into separate pieces, but is continuous; there are not discrete perfume-units inside the bottle, it's just a quantity of liquid. So to describe one scent caused by the application of one substance, we would call that a perfume. Where you would use perfumes is to talk about different varieties, such as one perfume named Sunshine and another perfume named Spring. They come in two different bottles and have two different scents, so they're two perfumes. When you apply one of them, however, it is simply a perfume. Behold: https://www.lexico.com/en/grammar/countable-nouns

Comment: Kindly add proof: It could be a link to a website by which you can justify and explain your answer.

Comment: Thank you very much Bella!